# Drupal Custom HTML Search Form

Tags: php, forms, drupal-7, drupal-search

I would like to display a custom search form in my Drupal site.

The search form has just a textbox and a submit button beside it, no need of any hidden fields.

I tried with a simple html form in my template, that mimics the normal drupal search form:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" id="search-form" method="post" action="/drupal/?q=search/page" class="search-form">
<div id="edit-basic" class="container-inline form-wrapper">
<div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-keys">
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="form-text" maxlength="255" size="40" name="keys" id="edit-keys" value="search" onBlur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'search'; }" onFocus="if(this.value == 'search') { this.value = ''; }" style="right:15px;">
</div>
</div>
<input type="hidden" value="form-Og2HsMomOhfRkoS262LFbqpN2NyIGeHHYfTF43Kynjs" name="form_build_id">
<input type="hidden" value="mfLsAR-y7CVQLcWY7hgZRGPbu3F3R5uQKKpZe3ppAi4" name="form_token">
<input type="hidden" value="search_form" name="form_id">
</form>
```

But that has got some problem like: “**The form has become outdated. Copy any unsaved work in the form below and then reload this page.**”

Is there a way i can use a custom html form as Drupal Search form ? Basically i want to redesign the default Drupal search form, to suit my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the default drupal search form and alter it as needed using [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7)

```
/** Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter */
function mymodule_form_search_form_alter (& $form, & $form_state)
{
  /* Do your alterations here */
}
```

Reference the [Form API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7) to help learn what changes you need to make.

Rplace mymodule in the code above with the name of your custom module. To output the form, in a template, use the below code:

```
$form = drupal_get_form('search_form');
print render($form);
```

Comment: Well, i finally used a module_invoke code to show the search form in my template as a block: **<?php $block = module_invoke('search', 'block_view', 'search'); print render($block); ?>**

Comment: Why couldn't you just use the Blocks page at admin/structure/block to display the search-form block? I imagined, obviously incorrectly, that there was a reason that using a block was inappropriate in your case.

Comment: Using module_invoke was one way, i also tried with theme_form_alter() in the template.php and made some custom changes to the form css. It worked well. Still accepting your answer, as it motivated me to look at the hook_form_alter().